# Использование функций get put eof

Tags: c++, вывод

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c;
    cout << "do vvoda cin.eof() ravnyaetsya " << cin.eof() << endl
        << "vvedite predlozhenie, zavershauysheesya priznakom konca fayla:"
        << endl;
    while ((c = cin.get()) != EOF)
        cout.put(c);
    cout << endl << "EOF v etoy sisteme ranyaetsya" << c << endl;
    cout << "posle vvoda cin.eof() ravnyaestsya " << cin.eof()
        << endl;
    system("pause");
        return 0;

}
```

**Почему тут используется переменная типа integer? ведь она позволяет в себе хранить только чила или я чего то не понимаю..**

Comment: потому что символы - это тоже числа. и строки - это числа (массивы чисел).

Comment: но ведь если просто вводить в инт символы то программа савершается а именно тут почему то работает

Comment: показывайте программу, которая вводит в инт символы и завершается, а также, что она должна бы сделать.

Comment: вот в этом примере она позволяет вводить любые символы пока не прервется Ctr+Z ;

а тут 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int c;
 cin >> c;
 cout << c;
  return 0;
}

она тут же прерывается если ввести что нибудь кроме числа

Comment: логично. Потому что `cin >> c` требует число. А `cin.get()` - требует символ. Все что Вы введете, можно представить в виде набора символов (которые кодируются числами от 0 до 255, если только не widechar). Но не всякий вывод - это число.

Если ещё проще -`cin >> c` получает набор символов, которые пытается интерпретировать как целое число (потому что `c` имеет тип `int`) и записать в `c`.

А `cin.get` ничего не интерпретирует.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение доступное , теперь все ясно))

Comment: @bleggleb, только вот, упоминаемый в вопросе .get() это не *вывод*, а **ввод** (т.е. меточку вы криво поправили -))

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `c` имеет тип `int`, потому что функция `std::istream::get()` возвращает `int` (см. примечание).

В случае, если поток закончился, то `get()` вернет значение обозначающее конец потока, и это значение обязано не входить в диапазон значений `char`. По этому используется более широкий тип - `int`.

Примечание:
на самом деле `get()` возвращает `int_type`, но это не важно в контексте данного вопроса, главное что `int_type` больше `char_type`.